# Ethereum Wallet takes forever to sync every day I open it. Is this practical?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

Does anyone agree that it is impractical to wait so VERY LONG every time I open my Ethereum Wallet and hit has to sync? What's up with that? Solutions?

Comment: There are several types of wallet, each its pros/cons, if you do not like the one you are using then you can switch to something else. If none of the existing wallet satisfy all your need then you have found a good opportunity to perhaps provide a service.

Comment: The Mist wallet is directly from Ethereum.org. If any of the "several types" you mention should have some value, it should be this one. So far it, and any wallet that requires a constant hours long sync, seems to be not thought about in advance ... and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: What sort of machine is this? I sync my wallet about once a week (parity) and it takes about 5 minutes (SSD, recent i7, 10mbps Internet).

Comment: Yep, my initial sync took with the official client took over a week, and each time I open it it takes over an hour to finish syncing. If that can't be fixed, Ethereum is practically useless.

Answer (score 1):

Normal users will not run a full node in the future. A full node takes a long time to sync and this will very likely not change in the future. As a normal user you will run a light-client that can sync way faster than a full node. Light clients are currently under development and slowly get usable. E.g. with geth you can start the light-client with "--light"

Comment: So, with a user not having to run a full node, they'll get the full most recent ledger without the sync? How does that work. Does the local client app just confirm with a remote machine on the web that is constantly adding/sync'ing the new blocks?

Comment: +1 to DudeVon Gregerz. I'd like to know how the light clients are supposed to be getting enough information without a full sync.

Comment: I am using `--light` to sync, it still takes me more than 3 days, and it hasn't finished yet.